# Spring 4 + Hibernate 5: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined

Tags: spring, transactionmanager

I have a problem with my project when I call a URL.
This is my applicationContext

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.prova" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        <!-- connection to datasource -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.prova.model"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
        name ="transactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>  
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />    
</beans>
```

This is my Controller

```
package com.prova.controller;
<!-- import -->

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

    public EmployeeController() {
        System.out.println("EmployeeController()");
    }

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all")
    public ModelAndView listEmployee(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Employee> listEmployee = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
        model.addObject("listEmployee", listEmployee);
        model.setViewName("home");
        return model;
    }
...
...
...
```

When I call in postman the url http://localhost:8082/prova/all I receive this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!
```

Please help me because I try all solutions.
Thanks!